# How to capture KeyboardInterrupt in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

UnitTests has a feature to capture `KeyboardInterrupt`, finishes a test and then report the results.

> **-c, --catch**
>
> *Control-C* during the test run waits for the current test to end and then reports all the results so far. A second *Control-C*
> raises the normal KeyboardInterrupt exception.
>
> See Signal Handling for the functions that provide this functionality.
>
> c.f. https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-options

In PyTest, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will just stop the session.

Is there a way to do the same as UniTests:

- Capture `KeyboardInterrupt`
- Finishes to execute the on-going test [optional]
- Skip other tests
- Display a result, and potentially print a report (e.g. usage of `pytest-html`)

Thanks

**[Edit 11 November 2016]**

I tried to put the hook in my `conftest.py` file but it does not seem to work and capture. In particular, the following does not write anything in `toto.txt`.

```
def pytest_keyboard_interrupt(excinfo):
    with open('toto.txt', 'w') as f: f.write("Hello")
    pytestmark = pytest.mark.skip('Interrupted Test Session')
```

Does anybody has a new suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue may lie in the execution ordering of your hook, such that pytest exits prior to your hook being executed. This could happen if an unhandled exception occurs in preexisting handling of the keyboard interrupt.

To ensure your hook executes sooner, use `tryfirst` or `hookwrapper` as described [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#hook-function-ordering-call-example).

The following shall be written in **conftest.py** file:

```
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_keyboard_interrupt(excinfo):
    with open('toto.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write("Hello")
    pytestmark = pytest.mark.skip('Interrupted Test Session')
```

Comment: Thanks @BHass for the answer. How to use `pytestmark` exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at pytest's [hookspec](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/hookspec.html).

They have a hook for keyword interrupt.

```
def pytest_keyboard_interrupt(excinfo):
""" called for keyboard interrupt. """
```

Comment: Looks like a good start. More specifically, how to use that without writing my own plugin?